# Regex to match at least n times but not more than m times

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression that could match the string `%*---` with at least 1 hyphen but the expression should not be matched if there are more than 3 hyphens.
So far I have come up with `/^%?\*{1}\s*(\- *){1,3}/` but it is still matching when the hyphens exceed 3.

I have also tried `?` after the range `{1,3}` but its not meeting the requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it's often written as `{min,max}` in tutorials and references, the enumerated quantifier does not mean *not more than `max`*.  If it sees three hyphens, `-{1,3}` will consume all three, but it doesn't care what the *next* character is (if there is one).  It's just like all other quantifiers in this regard: it consumes as much as it can, then it hands control to the next part of the regex.

That's why the other responders suggested using an end anchor (`$`).  If you can't use an anchor, or don't want to, you can use a negative lookahead instead:

```
/^%\*-{1,3}(?!-)/
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a `$` at the end, and your regex can be greatly simplified:

```
/^%\*--?-?$/
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/u7Y1QzBzxL).

Comment: actually i am writing perl regex, so $ is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!(.*?-){4})(?=.*?-).*$
```

You can try this.The lookahead will make sure there are no more than `3` `-` and at least `1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/12