# How to differenciate this two string with a REGEX?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to identify Spanish ID numbers using REGEX on MySQL. I am took [this regex](https://regex101.com/library/wZ9jG6?page=2) to adapt it to my dataset, as the items are not isolated and might not start/end with those characters. The expressions are:

Original: `^(x?\d{8}|[xyz]\d{7})[trwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke]$`

Mine:`[0-9]{8,8}[A-Za-z]{1}`

When I run the search using my REGEX, this is a sample of what I get:

- **GOOD** --> 47099085T
- **GOOD** --> D73654109H
- NOT OK --> 8.30781719e-05
- NOT OK --> 0113:11:19%2000:54:17.042828927Z

How can I modify `[0-9]{8,8}[A-Za-z]{1}` to exclude the "NOT OK" items?

Spanish ID syntax:

> The number of the National Identity Document includes 8 digits and one letter for security. The letter is found by taking all 8 digits as a number and dividing it by 23. The remainder of this digit, which is between 0 and 22, gives the letter used for security. The letters I, Ñ, O, U are not used. The letters I and O are not used – to avoid confusions with the numbers 0 and 1. The Ñ is not used to avoid confusions with N.

> ```
> Remainder:      0    1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
> Letter:         T    R    W   A   G   M   Y   F   P   D   X   B   N   J   Z   S   Q   V   H   L   C   K   E
> ```

**-- EDIT II --**

After running a test on a bigger data set, I have found other matches that should be excluded.

- How can I modify `(^|[^0-9.])([0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])` to DO NOT match:

  70ce4827ce88530583ed5a1a40245f24
  BE4-SGS-V2-00199982a5aa
  2945a6bf-86b6-4ea0-94d9-aec84980762d
  0x01010083B5627CCA663946A282DE573804AA85
  xmp.iid:FE7F11740720681189A59382544B2855

Comment: Maybe `^([A-Za-z][0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]?|[0-9]{8}[A-Za-z])$`? Or even `^[A-Za-z]?[0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]$`?

Comment: That change forces the string to start (^) with a number AND end ($) with a letter. The second case of the sample I shared start with letter and ends with letter, and it is valid. How can I exclude "." ":" and "-" from my expression to avoid the format of a exp number or date?

Comment: If your match is within a larger string, you should ensure there are spaces around your match: `\s[A-Za-z]?[0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]\s`. Once you get that, you can use MySQL [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function to remove them. Looks like this is the only way, given that MySQL does not support lookarounds.

Comment: @lemon the examples given show that this is not always the case. There is no guarentee of spaces around the ID string.

Comment: `\s` matches line feed too, it includes all "space-like" characters.

Comment: Why `D73654109H` is an allowed value? @JaviM

Comment: @lemon, the combination of numbers and last letter, is a valid ID. I have changed the data for privacy reasons. That example shows how a valid string can be sorounded by other characters that are not relevant. The first D in this case.

Comment: Please provide the official definition of a Spanish ID format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, according [to documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documento_Nacional_de_Identidad_(Spain)) the Spanish ID system (DNI) is structured thus:

> The number of the National Identity Document includes 8 digits and one letter for security. The letter is found by taking all 8 digits as a number and dividing it by 23. The remainder of this digit, which is between 0 and 22, gives the letter used for security. The letters I, Ñ, O, U are not used. The letters I and O are not used – to avoid confusions with the numbers 0 and 1. The Ñ is not used to avoid confusions with N.

> ```
> Remainder:      0    1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
> Letter:         T    R    W   A   G   M   Y   F   P   D   X   B   N   J   Z   S   Q   V   H   L   C   K   E
> ```

After some exploration with Negative Lookaheads and completely failing to get them to work, we can use a more manual approach to a solution, by manually checking that the found "block" of 8 integers is not preceeded by an integer or a decimal point:

```
/[^\.\d][\d]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]/gmi
```

MySQL safe/syntax version:

```
(^|[^0-9.])([0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])
```

Example usage using `REGEX_REPLACE` to return rows where the id_column matches the ID syntax and returns those syntax strings:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(`id_column`, 
    '(^|[^\\d.])(\\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])', '$2') as id_output
 FROM `table_name` 
 WHERE id_column REGEXP '(^|[^\\d.])(\\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])'
```

> **NOTE:** Prior to MySQL 8.0.17, the result returned by this function used the UTF-16 character set; in MySQL 8.0.17 and later, the character set and collation of the expression searched for matches is used. (Bug #94203, Bug #29308212)

This matches the two correct matches on your example as well as checking that only one of the valid letters comes after the numerical match.

It is important to note that using the *max* value in the qualifier `{min,max}` is pretty irrelevant because it **does not mean no more than *max* should exist in the source string**. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469827/3536236) for further reading.

What does my Regex do:

- Checks that a set of 8 integers is not preceeded by either another integer or a decimal point (so 9 integers are never "captured").
- Checks that the set of 8 found integers is immediately followed by one of the valid letters of either case.

You can see my Regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZDlBVr/1) and the corresponding MySQL demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WAdXxGmwcdCDWH7Bbk85G/5).

> ```
> 47099085T                         // matches 
> D73654109H                        // matches 
> 8.30781719e-05                    // unmatched 
> 0113:11:19%2000:54:17.042828927Z  // unmatched
> ```

Comment: @lemon this regex works on all versions of regex on Regex101.com as per the original regex101.com link given by the OP. OP has not stated which version of MySQL they use but overviewing the [MySQL compatibility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility) there is no reason to think that without some very minor syntax tweaking this should work fine, at least in MySQL 8+

Comment: @lemon I have added MySQL syntax and example code.

Comment: @Martin, that regex works like a charm. You are the man!